# Mailgun: How to bulk validate email in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun, email-validation, bulk

I am trying to implement bulk email validation using Mailgun API in Ruby.
As per their API doc https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-email-validation.html#bulk-validation, I need to pass LIST_ID while calling API. But in my case, I have a dynamic list of email ids to be bulk validated. I am not sure, how to call and send API with the list of email addresses. Can someone provide an example or direct to documentation with examples?
Thanks.

Comment: Chintan, you should read documents carefully and try to figureout. The help you are asking is not encouraged. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing it using gem Mailgun-ruby.
Here is the code:

```
mailgun_client = Mailgun::Client.new(PRIVATE_API_KEY, 'api.mailgun.net', 'v4')
# submit bulk validation job
mailgun_client.post('address/validate/bulk/1', { :file => File.new('/Users/user/Documents/mailgun_bulk.csv') })
# fetch response for bulk validation job
mailgun_client.get('address/validate/bulk/1')
```